# Python Sqlite3 insert operation with a list of column names

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

Normally, if i want to insert values into a table, i will do something like this (assuming that i know which columns that the values i want to insert belong to):

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('mydatabase.db')
conn.execute("INSERT INTO MYTABLE (ID,COLUMN1,COLUMN2)\
VALUES(?,?,?)",[myid,value1,value2])
```

But now i have a list of columns (the length of list may vary) and a list of values for each columns in the list.

For example, if i have a table with 10 columns (Namely, column1, column2...,column10 etc). I have a list of columns that i want to update.Let's say `[column3,column4]`. And i have a list of values for those columns. `[value for column3,value for column4]`.

How do i insert the values in the list to the individual columns that each belong?

Comment: In the code example you write "VALUES(?,?)" where there seems to be a question mark missing, since you're trying to pass three values.

Comment: @starrify typo but that was just an example

Comment: Yes and I'm only pointing out that typo XD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know the parameter list in `conn.execute` works only for values, so we have to use string formatting like this:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
conn.execute('CREATE TABLE t (a integer, b integer, c integer)')
col_names = ['a', 'b', 'c']
values = [0, 1, 2]
conn.execute('INSERT INTO t (%s, %s, %s) values(?,?,?)'%tuple(col_names), values)
```

**Please notice** this is a very bad attempt since strings passed to the database shall always be checked for injection attack. However you could pass the list of column names to some injection function before insertion.

**EDITED:**
For variables with various length you could try something like

```
exec_text = 'INSERT INTO t (' + ','.join(col_names) +') values(' + ','.join(['?'] * len(values)) + ')'
conn.exec(exec_text, values)
# as long as len(col_names) == len(values)
```

Comment: but my problem is that the length of the list always change. Sometimes i may need to just change 2 columns, sometimes 3 to 4. So, string formatting won't work for me. But thanks for the help.

Comment: @ChrisAung Well I'm only providing a simple example.. For various length lists you could try `'INSERT INTO t (' + ','.join(col_names) +') values(' + ','.join(['?'] * len(values)) + ')', values`, while `len(col_names) == len(values)`

Answer (score 3):

Of course string formatting will work, you just need to be a bit cleverer about it.

```
col_names = ','.join(col_list)
col_spaces = ','.join(['?'] * len(col_list))
sql = 'INSERT INTO t (%s) values(%s)' % (col_list, col_spaces)
conn.execute(sql, values)
```

Comment: well plz don't forget `values(?,?,?)` won't work for col_list with length other than 3 :D

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a solution to create columns based on a list of unknown / variable length and found this question. However, I managed to find a nicer solution (for me anyway), that's also a bit more modern, so thought I'd include it in case it helps someone:

```
import sqlite3

def create_sql_db(my_list):

    file = 'my_sql.db'
    table_name = 'table_1'
    init_col = 'id'
    col_type = 'TEXT'

    conn = sqlite3.connect(file)
    c = conn.cursor()

    # CREATE TABLE (IF IT DOESN'T ALREADY EXIST)
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {tn} ({nf} {ft})'.format(
        tn=table_name, nf=init_col, ft=col_type))

    # CREATE A COLUMN FOR EACH ITEM IN THE LIST
    for new_column in my_list:
        c.execute('ALTER TABLE {tn} ADD COLUMN "{cn}" {ct}'.format(
            tn=table_name, cn=new_column, ct=col_type))

    conn.close()


my_list = ["Col1", "Col2", "Col3"]

create_sql_db(my_list)
```

All my data is of the type text, so I just have a single variable "col_type" - but you could for example feed in a list of tuples (or a tuple of tuples, if that's what you're into):

```
my_other_list = [("ColA", "TEXT"), ("ColB", "INTEGER"), ("ColC", "BLOB")]
```

and change the CREATE A COLUMN step to:

```
for tupl in my_other_list:

    new_column = tupl[0]   # "ColA", "ColB", "ColC"
    col_type = tupl[1]     # "TEXT", "INTEGER", "BLOB"

    c.execute('ALTER TABLE {tn} ADD COLUMN "{cn}" {ct}'.format(
        tn=table_name, cn=new_column, ct=col_type))
```

Answer (score 0):

As a noob, I can't comment on the very succinct, updated solution @ron_g offered. While testing, though I had to frequently delete the sample database itself, so for any other noobs using this to test, I would advise adding in:

```
     c.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {tn}'.format(
    tn=table_name))
```

Prior the the 'CREATE TABLE ...' portion.

It appears there are multiple instances of

```
.format(
    tn=table_name ....)
```

in both 'CREATE TABLE ...' and 'ALTER TABLE ...' so trying to figure out if it's possible to create a single instance (similar to, or including in, the def section).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).